# Personality quiz based on a total sum

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I'm having trouble finding a way to show the total value along with displaying a certain outcome based on their score. Such as if total >= 400 then display Apple. If else 400

HTML - This is an example answer

```
<h3>Pick a color</h3>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' name="color" value="20" />
            <span class="checkable">Red</span>
        </label>
    </p>
```

JavaScript - How I will calculate the totals but i cant seem to display the total on the html. The two things I am adding is Color and Social for those are 2 question IDs i have but cannot fit into this question.

```
    var quiz = {}
    quiz.view = function (state, props) {
        state.$color = state.$social = {
            _onclick: function (event) {
                props.totals[this.name] = parseInt(this.value)
            }
        }
        state.results = props.totals.color + props.total.social
    }

    var props = {
        totals: {
            social: 0,
            color: 0,
        }
    }
    mag.module("quiz", quiz, props);
```

Comment: It looks that this question is related to Magento. Added the tag. Please remove if not relevent

Comment: You can't use `document.write(totals);` inside object declaration. Its invalid and syntax is wrong.